# Moving maximum and LTI in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I've implement a moving maximum filter in matlab and now I have to determine if it's LTI or not. I've already prove it's linear but I can't prove if it's time ivnariant. To prove this I have to give as an input a signal `x[n]` and get the output `X[n]`. After that I'm giving the same signal but this time it have to delay it that is `x[n-a]` and the output must be `X[n-a]` the same as the `X[n]` but delayed. My problem is that I don't know what input to give. Also, the moving maximum is a LTI system or not?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could give it a unit step. Probably something more preferable though is a truncated function, maybe a sinusoid of some sort so you can see the delays easily. A truncated function will also allow you to see the effects of the maximum filter.

Comment: Well I'll give you a clue of what I gave as an input so far. First I gave this x1 = 0:1:10 and I did all the things a said before BUT I only get one different output when I use the stem function to compare the results. I stem the X[n] and X[n-a] and there is only one differnce. Then I use the unit step function like this: t = (-5:1:10), x = zeros(size(t)), x(t>=0) - 1; And again the same result

Comment: Can you post all the code and your implementation of the filter in the question?

Comment: Ok, give me a sec. But my thinking is right so far? I mean I'm doing somethin wrong?

Comment: I assume `w` is the window size?

Comment: Yes. There is a change that the matlab might have a problem? Maybe it prints something wrong?

Comment: In that case, the code breaks down for a few window sizes. Also when inputting a ramp it should reproduce a ramp as the filtered output. Any reason for not using `conv()` or `movemax()` functions?

Comment: My professor gave us this. In fact he gave us moving average and told us to modify it. So I'm not pretty sure if I'm allowed use these functions you said... So are you telling is that I have to check it for more window sizes?

Comment: I can show you how'd I do it from scratch but it might differ significantly.

Comment: Ok if you don't mind show me, maybe it'll help me. If I use a bigger window size you think that will work?

Comment: Typically filter code should work for any window size. Alright, I'll get to creating it.

Comment: Omg really? I really really appreciate it. If you don't have free time it's okay I don't wanna bother you... Thanks a lot.

Comment: _I've already prove it's linear_ If I understand your question correctly, it's not linear. Consider the output for a Dirac delta, the output for a time-shifted Dirac delta, and the output for the sum of those two functions

Answer (score 0):

### Max-Filter Using For-Loop and Testing System for Linear and Time-Invariance

**Filter Construction:**

To filter an array/matrix/signal a for-loop can be applied. Within this for-loop, portions of the signal that overlaps the window must be stored in this case called `Window_Sample`. To apply the maximum filter the `max()` of the `Window_Sample` must be taken upon each iteration of the loop. Upon each iteration of the loop the window moves. Here I push all the code that calculates the maximum filtered signal into a function called `Max_Filter()`.

---

**Time-Invariant or Not-Time Invariant:**

With proper padding, I think the maximum filter is time-invariant/shift-invariant. Concatenating zeros to the start and ends of the signal is a good way to combat this. The amount of padding I used on each end is the size of the window, the requirement would be half the window but there's no harm in having a little bit of buffer. Unfortunately, without proper padding, this may appear to break down in MATLAB since the max filter will be introduced to points early. In this case without padding the ramp the max filter will take the 5th point as the max right away. Here you can apply a scaling factor to test if the system is linear. You'll see that the system is not linear since the output is not a scaled version of the input.

[image: Max Filtering Signal]

```
clf;
%**********************************************************%
%ADJUSTABLE PARAMETERS%
%**********************************************************%
Window_Size = 3; %Window size for filter%
Delay_Size = 5; %Delay for the second test signal%
Scaling_Factor = 1; %Scaling factor for the second test signal%

n = (0:10);
%Ramp function with padding%
Signal = n; %Function for test signal% 
%**********************************************************%

Signal = [zeros(1,Window_Size) Signal zeros(1,Window_Size)];
Filtered_Result_1 = Max_Filter(Signal,Window_Size);

%Ramp function with additional delay%
Delayed_Signal = Scaling_Factor.*[zeros(1,Delay_Size) Signal];
Filtered_Result_2 = Max_Filter(Delayed_Signal,Window_Size);

plot(Filtered_Result_1);
hold on
plot(Filtered_Result_2);
xlabel("Samples [n]"); ylabel("Amplitude");
title("Moving Maximum Filtering Signal");
legend("Original Signal","Delayed Signal");
xticks([0: 1: length(Filtered_Result_2)]);
xlim([0 length(Filtered_Result_2)]);
grid;


function [Filtered_Signal] = Max_Filter(Signal,Filter_Size)

%Initilizing an array to store filtered signal%
Filtered_Signal = zeros(1,length(Signal));

%Filtering array using for-loop and acccesing chunks%
for Sample_Index = 1: length(Signal)

    Start_Of_Window = Sample_Index - floor(Filter_Size/2);
    End_Of_Window = Sample_Index + floor(Filter_Size/2);

    if Start_Of_Window < 1
        Start_Of_Window = 1;   
    end

    if End_Of_Window > length(Signal)
        End_Of_Window = length(Signal);
    end

    Window_Sample = Signal(Start_Of_Window:End_Of_Window);    
    Filtered_Signal(1,Sample_Index) = max(Window_Sample);

end

end
```

---

### Alternatively Using Built-In Functions:

To test the results of the created filter it is a good idea to compare this to the output results of MATLAB's built-in function `movmax()`. Here the results appear to be the same as the for-loop implementation.

```
clf;
Window_Size = 3;
n = (0:10);

%Ramp function with padding%
Signal = n;
Signal = [zeros(1,Window_Size) Signal zeros(1,Window_Size)];
Filtered_Result_1 = movmax(Signal,Window_Size);

%Ramp function with additional delay%
Delay_Size = 5; 
Delayed_Signal = [zeros(1,Delay_Size) Signal];
Filtered_Result_2 = movmax(Delayed_Signal,Window_Size);

plot(Filtered_Result_1);
hold on
plot(Filtered_Result_2);
xlabel("Samples [n]"); ylabel("Amplitude");
title("Moving Maximum Filtering Signal");
legend("Original Signal","Delayed Signal");
xticks([0: 1: length(Filtered_Result_2)]);
xlim([0 length(Filtered_Result_2)]);
grid;
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**

Comment: I'd like to ask you something else. If I modify a little bit different my moving maximum it will work as it suppose to do? You know how? Maybe what I did is not enough to work the filter and it maybe needs something else

Comment: I'm not too sure, did you make an edit to the code. I didn't see it posted.